# How can I make concurrent requests faster with Retrofit / OkHttp?

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, okhttp

I need to make 50 http GET requests as fast as possible with Retrofit in Android. I am using Retrofit with OkHttp. Currently Retrofit is doing a poor job vs plain Java `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `HttpUrlConnection`: about 50sec for Retrofit and 30sec for plain `HttpUrlConnection` for all 50 requests, if I set the pool size 20 for `ThreadPoolExecutor` and for Retrofit / OkHttp I set `okHttpClient.dispatcher().setMaxRequests(20);`.

If I look at logcat I can see that Retrofit is doing maximum of 5 concurrent requests no matter what I set in `setMaxRequests()` while with `ThreadPoolExecutor` there are as many concurrent requests as there are available worker threads.

Is there anything I can do to make Retrofit faster? I don't want to switch to `HttpUrlConnection` because Retrofit is so elegant and easy to use.

### Edit 1

I tried providing custom `ThreadPoolExecutor` to OkHttp but no time improvement from this:

```
OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
ExecutorService exec = new ThreadPoolExecutor(20, 20, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS, new LinkedBlockingQueue<>());
Dispatcher d = new Dispatcher(exec);
builder.dispatcher(d);
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
okHttpClient.dispatcher().setMaxRequests(20);
```

### Edit 2

I make all requests to the same endpoint, if this matters

Comment: I'd consider posting that as bug request here: https://github.com/square/retrofit hoping to get some feedback from devs

Comment: Hi Could you please tell what have you done to solve this issue ? even am facing the same issue no matter how much we set it is taking default of 5 connections

Answer (score 13):

Since they are all going to the same host, have you tried:

```
okHttpClient.dispatcher().setMaxRequestsPerHost(20);
```

[Dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/Dispatcher.html#setMaxRequestsPerHost-int-)

Answer (score 1):

both `dispatcher.maxRequests = 20` and `dispatcher.maxRequestsPerHost = 20` did the job for me

With some Kotlin example

```
package com.package



/**
 * Created by touhid on 24/Jan/2022.
 */
object NetworkService {

    private val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply {
        apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }
    }
    private val okClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .addInterceptor { chain ->

            val token = getToken(chain)
            var newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
            token?.let {
                newRequest = newRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $it")
                newRequest = newRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            }
            chain.proceed(newRequest.build())
        }
        .addInterceptor(interceptor)

        .build().also {
            it.dispatcher.maxRequests = 20
            it.dispatcher.maxRequestsPerHost = 20
        }


    private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .client(okClient)
        .baseUrl(Constants.baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()

    val service: myApiService = retrofit.create(FoodicsApi::class.java)

    

}
```